# Change SO topbar style using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using:

`document.getElementsByClassName("topbar")[0].style.background = "#FFFFFF";`

The StackOverflow `topbar` CSS is

```
.topbar {
width: 100%;
background: #2f2f2f;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.86);
height: 34px;
line-height: 1;
}
```

so why isn't it working? My Javascript code does nothing! I'm new to Javascript, so please be easy on me:)

Comment: you miss the `.style` ... `document.getElementsByClassName("topbar")[0].style.background = "#FFFFFF";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention Chrome, you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) and [`.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) to change the background color:

```
document.querySelector(".topbar").style.background = "#FFFFFF";
```

Comment: @chris where do you paste this? in the console? in a Chrome extension? I hope not in the address bar

Comment: @chris Are you waiting for the DOM to be loaded? Are you putting this in a _contentscript_ ?(the script needs to execute on the page, not in the extension's background page)

Comment: "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://stackoverflow.com/*"],
      "js": ["src/cs.js"]
    }

Comment: nm, had a typo. thanks for the `queryselector`, never knew about it!

Comment: @chris, Sorry, that was lame of me.  I forgot about this answer, glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I'm very curious what you might be trying to achieve here, but to answer your question, `background` is a property of the `style` object:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("topbar")[0].style.background = "#FFFFFF";
```

Comment: To clarify: I'm trying to change StackOverflow's 'topbar' color.

Comment: +1, I just pasted that in my javascript console and it works. @chris I'm on Chrome too, (Hit _F12_ to get the console and just paste it without 'javascript')

Comment: Why don't you try `document.querySelector(".topbar").style.background = "#FFFFFF";`?